# Converting a String to byte[] for decryption

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption

im facing a problem in my code.

I want to encrypt the Password from the user and save it to an SQL Database.
The Code im Using to Encrypt the Password with AES:

```
        String key = "1234567890123456"; // 128 bit key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(Passwort.getBytes());
        String verschlüsselt = new String(encrypted);
```

Now im saving the String "verschlüsselt" to my Database.

In my LoginGUI im getting the String with the Password from the database:

```
         String psswd = res.getString("Passwort"); //Getting the Password from Database and saving it into String
         System.out.println(psswd);
```

The PrintOut is: "!?¿[ŸÊm,r~¤u" which is the correct encrypted password.

Now i'm trying to decrypt the password with following code:

```
     String key = "1234567890123456"; // 128 bit key
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
     EPasswort = new String(cipher.doFinal(bpsswd)); //Im facing the problem here
```

I Know that i can't decrypt the String and that I have to convert the String into an byte[].
I've done that in several ways:

```
          byte[] password = psswd.getBytes();
          System.out.println(password);
          password = psswd.getBytes("UTF-8");
          System.out.println(password);
          EPasswort = new String(cipher.doFinal(password));
```

But the Output is always something the decrypter can't work with:

```
[B@ab33b4
[B@189090b
```

How do i convert my String with the Password (!?¿[ŸÊm,r~¤u) into an byte[] so my decrypter can work with it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: encrypt the password and then match with the db password.

Comment: The byte to string conversion and back to byte will fail because of many "non-printable" characters like a (hex) x00 byte. Better, you are using the Base64 en- and later decoding function. Secondly: for your encryption you have chosen the ECB mode that is a terrible choice, especially when encrypting passwords (there are lots of better choices to use, e.g. BCrypt). If you should need the user giving password, you should encrypt the data using the **GCM mode**. BTW: it's better to use variable names without umlauts, like "ü" in "verschlüsselt". Greetings to Germany, Austria or Switzerland :-)

Comment: `I want to encrypt the Password from the user and save it to an SQL Database.` if it's for user authentication, do not *encrypt* the password, but use *slow salted hash*  (bcrypt, scrypt,... pbkdf2)

Answer (score 2):

You should encrypt the String and than save it as a String, in this example I'm using a Base64 encoder and a different cypher but the logic behind is the same. You should save bytes or String instead of using the reference to your bytes, here an example:

```
@Test
public void testCrypt () {
    
    final String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;
    final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12;
    final int SALT_LENGTH_BYTE = 16;
    
    final String password = "password";

    final byte[] salt = getRandomNonce(SALT_LENGTH_BYTE);
    final byte[] iv = getRandomNonce(IV_LENGTH_BYTE);
    final SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword = getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt);
    
    String msg = "Test";
    String out = "";
    try {
        out = encrypt(ENCRYPT_ALGO, TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv, aesKeyFromPassword, msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    byte[] plainText = new byte[0];
    try {
        plainText = decrypt(ENCRYPT_ALGO, TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv, aesKeyFromPassword, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Decrypted " + out + " in: " + new String(plainText, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
}
```

following the encrypt method:

```
private String encrypt(final String ENCRYPT_ALGO, final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT, final byte[] iv,
        final SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword, String msg) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    final byte[] pText = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));

    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pText);

    String out = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    System.out.println("Encrypted " + msg + " as: " + out);
    return out;
}


private static SecretKey getAESKeyFromPassword(final char[] password, final byte[] salt) {
    final int KEY_LENGTH = 128;
    final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
    
    try {
        final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        final KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new RedException(e);
    }
}

private static byte[] getRandomNonce(final int numBytes) {
    final byte[] nonce = new byte[numBytes];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonce);
    return nonce;
}
```

Once you save the `msgCrypted` in db you should retrieve it and process it to decrypt like this:

```
private byte[] decrypt(final String ENCRYPT_ALGO, final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT, final byte[] iv,
        final SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword, String out) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher dCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
    dCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
    final byte[] plainText = dCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(out));
    return plainText;
}
```

In the console you should have something like this:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Maybe you should consider giving a full running example. I know what the "ENCRYPT_ALGO" - string has to be, but a beginner won't find a solution. Second: The GCM mode needs a nonce (recommended size of 12 bytes, here named with "iv") that should get generated randomly and send to the receiver (accompanied by the ciphertext) - you should give an example how to do this. Thanks for choosing AES in GCM mode instead of unsecure ECB mode.

Comment: Thanks for helping improving my answer. I edited it to give a full example.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Just a final note: why are you limiting the PBKDF2-key derivation to 16 bytes (for AES-128) and not using 32 bytes (for AES-256) as default ? :-)

Comment: There's no particular reason, I imagine it would be better to leave it as default instead. I appreciate your help once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the reference to the byte array, not the elements.

Run this for demonstration:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String s = "12345678";
    byte [] b = s.getBytes ();
    System.out.println (b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.println (b [i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[B@7a81197d
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
```